# Unique Array objects in mongoose schema

Tags: express, mongoose

I have a conversation schema which will allow users for private messaging, each two users can be in `ONE` conversation therefore, the recipients in the conversations should be unique

```
/** Users in this conversation**/
var usersSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        index: true,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

/** For each message we will have the below **/
var messagesSchema = new Schema({
    from: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    read: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


/** Now all together inside the thread schema **/
var conversationsSchema = new Schema({

    users: {
        type: [usersSchema],
        required: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true
    },
    messages: [messagesSchema],


}, {
    timestamps: true
});

var Conversation = mongoose.model('Conversation', conversationsSchema);
module.exports.Conversation = Conversation;
```

The only way I can think of is to manually check by looking into the IDs inside the users array in the conversation schema. However, I think there is a way in mongoose to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `unique : true` in your userSchema to only allow unique users in a conversation.

```
/** Users in this conversation**/
var usersSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        index: true,
        required: true,
        unique : true, //add unique behaviour here
        ref: 'User'
    },

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```